# popup window on web map

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, esri-maps

i have displayed my map on web by using arcgis javascript api sample. in the sample it display a popup window but on my side it does not. now i want to add popup window. i want when user click on the different type of soil a popup window will open and display the attributes of the layers

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Create web map from JSON</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    <script>
      require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/dom",
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        "esri/urlUtils",
        "esri/arcgis/utils",
        "esri/dijit/Legend",
        "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        parser,
        ready,
        BorderContainer,
        ContentPane,
        dom,
        Map,
        Extent,
        urlUtils,
        arcgisUtils,
        Legend,
        Scalebar
      ) {
        ready(function(){

        parser.parse();

        var webmap = {};
        webmap.item = {
          "title":"Soil Map",
         "snippet": "This map shows the Soil types",
          "extent": [[73.94251383600005, 31.02571637300008],[74.05297753900004, 31.11529292900019]]
        };

        webmap.itemData = {
          "operationalLayers": [{
            "url": "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Soil_Maps/soil_map/MapServer",
            "visibility": true,
            "opacity": 0.75,
            "title": "Soil Survey Map",
            
          }],
          "baseMap": {
            "baseMapLayers": [{
              "opacity": 1,
              "visibility": true,
              "url": "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Terrain_Base/MapServer"
              },{
              "isReference": true,
              "opacity": 1,
              "visibility": true,
              "url": "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Reference_Overlay/MapServer"
              }],
            "title": "World_Terrain_Base"
          },
          "version": "1.1"
        };

        dom.byId("title").innerHTML = webmap.item.title;
        dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = webmap.item.snippet;

        arcgisUtils.createMap(webmap,"map").then(function(response){


          var map = response.map;



          //add the scalebar 
          var scalebar = new Scalebar({
            map: map,
            scalebarUnit: "english"
          });

          //add the legend. Note that we use the utility method getLegendLayers to get 
          //the layers to display in the legend from the createMap response.
          var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response); 
          var legendDijit = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos: legendLayers
          },"legend");
          legendDijit.startup();


        });


        });

      });

    </script>
```

```html
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
      <div id="header" class="shadow roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="subtitle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="map" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
      <div id="rightPane" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'" >
        <div id="legend"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended that we should use webmap/item id instead of webmap json.

Once you are able to get the webmap id or item id then using below code you can consume the webmap-

```js
require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/dom",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/urlUtils",
        "esri/arcgis/utils",
        "esri/dijit/Legend",
        "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        parser,
        ready,
        BorderContainer,
        ContentPane,
        dom,
        Map,
        urlUtils,
        arcgisUtils,
        Legend,
        Scalebar
      ) {
        ready(function(){

        parser.parse();


//***** change webmapid only
arcgisUtils.createMap("ef9c7fbda731474d98647bebb4b33c20","map").then(function(response){
          

          var map = response.map;



          //add the scalebar
          var scalebar = new Scalebar({
            map: map,
            scalebarUnit: "english"
          });

          //add the legend. Note that we use the utility method getLegendLayers to get
          //the layers to display in the legend from the createMap response.
          var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
          var legendDijit = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos: legendLayers
          },"legend");
          legendDijit.startup();


        });


        });

      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/ags_createwebmapid/css/layout.css">

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">

      <div id="map" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
      <div id="rightPane" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'" >
        <div id="legend"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Note:-** Update the code as per comments in it

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Comment: do you know how to do this by using highmaps? i have lot of maps of diffrent area to display

Answer (score 0):

well, As i can see in snippet code webmap json doesn't contain infowindow/popup configuration settings because of that i think its is not visible in you sample.

**However recommended way** is to create an online esri webmap which will handle all those complications for you. 
and add your esri mapserver in the webmap. after that configure the popup for the layer.

Creating a webmap is very simple process, below are the steps to do that-

1. Choose basemap
2. Add layers
3. Change style
4. Configure **pop-ups**
5. Save map
6. share the webmap

**source webmap:-** http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-web-map.htm

**source steps:-** http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/get-started/get-started-with-maps.htm

If you need more info let me know i will update accordingly.

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Comment: i donot have license of arcgis online. is there anyother way to do this ?

Comment: Create a trial account and publish the webmap using that account. No need to pay and buy for one time. But if you feel its good and useful then buy it....

Comment: but i have a lot maps to display. i need some smart solution.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513503/barchart-in-popup-with-string-values-on-label

Comment: kindly look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513503/barchart-in-popup-with-string-values-on-label

Comment: i want to show modal on clicking feature layer $('#myModal').modal('show'); but it gives error

Comment: kindly help me solving this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896915/weather-information-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you have misused "esri/urlUtils" module,it mainly [provides utility methods to work with content from ArcGIS.com](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.urlutils-amd.html). 
So you can not use its createMap method to create map with your local arcgis server map service,instead you should publish your operational layers through arcgis.com,and get map item id.see [how to Publish hosted feature layers by csv or featurelayer](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm) .

1.Using "esri/urlUtils" module to create map

you can create map using "esri/urlUtils" module's creatMap method either with json or itemid.

1) create web map by json,for complete code see
 developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ags_createwebmapitem.html

```
webmap.itemData = {
                "operationalLayers": [{
                    "url": "xxx",// your map service goes here
                    "visibility": true,
                    "opacity": 0.75,
                    "title": "Soil Survey Map",
                    "itemId": "xx"//your map item id in arcgis.com
      }],...
```

NOTE:JSON should include your operational layer item id in arcgis.com

2) create web map by itemid(*recommended*),for complete code see
 developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ags_createwebmapid.html

```
            ready(function () {

            parser.parse();

            //if accessing webmap from a portal outside of ArcGIS Online, uncomment and replace path with portal URL
            //arcgisUtils.arcgisUrl = "https://pathto/portal/sharing/content/items";
            arcgisUtils.createMap("ef9c7fbda731474d98647bebb4b33c20", "map").then(function (response) {
                //update the app
                dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
                dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

                var map = response.map;



                //add the scalebar
                var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                    map: map,
                    scalebarUnit: "english"
                });

                //add the legend. Note that we use the utility method getLegendLayers to get
                //the layers to display in the legend from the createMap response.
                var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
                var legendDijit = new Legend({
                    map: map,
                    layerInfos: legendLayers
                }, "legend");
                legendDijit.startup();
            });
        });
```

2.add popup,for some samples see developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/#search/Popup

If you have a lot maps to display,you should use featurelayer to add data to map.for details please see the ags js api documentation.